# Network bridge loses its IP configuration

Tags: networking, windows-8, ip, dhcp

After certain uptime of my computer, network bridge adapter (includes WLAN and virtual machine) in my Windows 8 computer suddenly deconfigures from 192.168.1.9 (address made static at router's DHCP server for this computer) to automatically assigned 169.254.84.223. The latter address is from [segment of special use](http://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/169.254.84.223/) - for not configured devices. For the record I note the subnet mask is changed, too, from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.0.0.

[image]

Then, if I issue `ipconfig /release` or `ipconfig /renew`, the command freezes, not giving any output for a long time. Only `^C` helps. If I configure manual IP address via control panel, UI freezes and must be killed. However, the config is saved so at least I can manually revert that strange situation.

Inspecting **router logs**, there is a DHCP deassignment message (most likely received from the computer) although I was actively using computer at the moment, doing some other work. But I do not suspect that deassignment was initiated by the router. Other connected devices do not have this problem, while on this computer this is its 3rd occurence. (And Windows restart always helped to fix it.)
[image]

**How such an IP deconfiguration can happen without any action on my side?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the MAC address used. 
Let me explain:

Windows uses two or more devices for the bridge. Now the MAC of the bridge will be set accordingly to the lowest address in the stack. The MAC itself will also be slightly changed to avoid conflicting with your real MACs.
If you created a static ip dhcp entry for your bridge, it is possible that one of your devices were not or stopped working and the ip entry set by you was deassigned but windows did not issue a DHCP renew packet.

Try add a static entry for each of those addresses and see how it goes.

Comment: Very interesting answer. I added static DHCP entry also for second bridged adapter as you suggested. Let's wait for the result. Anyway, it seems you hit the point, because before the bridge's MAC address was set according to WiFi adapter (it seems it took its MAC address), now it seems to be set according to virtual machine adapter. (I've verified MAC addresses by temporarily removing devices from the bridge, then it was possible to display their addresses.)

Comment: Maybe I'll also consider [setting unique MAC address](http://serverfault.com/questions/345456/how-can-i-change-the-mac-address-of-a-network-bridge-in-windows) to the bridge.

Comment: @miroxlav I'd wait a bit to see if this was the cause. But otherwise, sure, you can use it. Just remember to test it by disabling each device one by one and note the MAC address.